# how can i select file with several directories below?

Tags: linux, bash

i'm very new to this so apologies for my simple question. I tried a few things but failed. Let's say I'm in directory a. I have files under my 2 directories that I need to select and process. but when i try to do it it says file not found.

The extension of the files is gz. by the way, the file name is also long and changes according to the directory it is in. This is the first step of what I have to do. After doing this, I need to do other things in the same loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

for k in {1..9}; do
rnxEditGde.py -data "y2019/d${k}/*.gz" -o dataRecordFile.Orig.gz
rinex2StaDb.py "y2019/d${k}/*.gz" -outFile sta.sta_db
done
```

Comment: The `*` works only if it is unquoted. Try `"y2019/d${k}/"*.gz`

Comment: I think this is the first time I have seen an error because of quotes. Usually it is the other way around: People ask because they did not know that quoting is needed when dealing with special symbols (e.g. spaces). Glad to see a beginner using quotes from the beginning =)